# Angular 9 Reset form to original state where one field is an array

Tags: angular, angular9

I will be grabbing some data from my API where the user will have the option to edit some values. One of form controls is an array. The issue I am having is when the user wants to undo / revert their changes, the array of nicknames does not change. What am I doing wrong here?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kedpa6

Comment: You posted the link to the empty Angular template.

Comment: Share your code

Comment: Sorry about that. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kedpa6 updated the link.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that while assigning the form group value it is not creating a deep copy of those values.
Replace the following constructor with yours or follow this link [Edited Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qfe2w8)

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder ){
    // this.original = this.form.value;
    this.original = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.form.value));
}
```